# Trying to keep user logged in using firebase auth in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have a react app using firebase for authentication & other tools. On a certain page, I check if the user is logged in using `firebase.auth().currentUser;` & also tried with `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` but it redirects me to the login page indicating I was not logged whereas I just logged in.

Here is the code for what I have tried so far :

```
const [user, setUser] = React.useState(firebase.auth().currentUser);

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      setUser(user);
    }
  })

  React.useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
      }
    })
  });
return(

    <Styles>
    { user ?
      <Paper className={clsx(classes.root, "Paper")}>

        <div className="overlay"></div>

        <Container maxWidth="lg">

          <HeaderTypography variant="h2" color="" gutterBottom>
            Create an Event
          </HeaderTypography> : <Redirect to="/login"/> }
```

Even after logging in, when I come to this page I still get redirected .. Any help will be welcomed

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have all of your component's ending tags. Also have a parathesis wrapped around the main  `Paper` component. The below code will work.
For example:

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async(userData) => {
      console.log(userData);
      if (userData) {
         setUser(userData);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    user ?
    (<Paper className={clsx(classes.root, "Paper")}>

        <div className="overlay"></div>

        <Container maxWidth="lg">

          <HeaderTypography variant="h2" color="" gutterBottom>
            Create an Event
          </HeaderTypography>
        </Container>
    </Paper>) :
    <Redirect to="/login"/>

  );
}
```

Comment: Still redirects me to login unfortunately :/

Comment: Can you please add a reproducible code in https://codesandbox.io? Would be quicker to fix.